# What is $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{x}{e^{-x}+x-1}\right)^x$

Tags: limits

What is

> $$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x}{e^{-x}+x-1}\right)^x$$

Using the expansion of [$e^x$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function), I get that the function

> $$y=\left(\frac{x}{e^{-x}+x-1}\right)^x$$

is not defined for negative numbers.

Hence the limit at $0^{-}$ must not exist.$\implies$The limit at $0$ does not exist.

However [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%28x%2F%28%28e%5E%28-x%29%29%2Bx-1%29%29%5Ex+as+x+tends+to+0) says that it should be $1$. :(

Am I wrong?

Comment: WA probably only considers positive values of x (in which case the limit is indeed 1).

Comment: But for the limit to be defined, the LHL and RHL must both exist and be equal. If WA doesn't consider that, then is WA wrong?

Comment: Actually I withdraw my first comment. Look at the diagram on the WA page: WA considers bilateral limits and interprets powers of negative real numbers as complex logarithms, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WA interprets the number
$$
u(x)=\left(\frac{x}{\mathrm e^{-x}+x-1}\right)^x
$$
when $x\gt0$ as
$$
u(x)=\exp\left(x\log\left(\frac{x}{\mathrm e^{-x}+x-1}\right)\right),
$$
and when $x\lt0$ as
$$
u(x)=\exp\left(x\log\left(\frac{-x}{\mathrm e^{-x}+x-1}\right)+\mathrm i\pi x\right).
$$
Then both limits are indeed $1$ (as one sees when one looks closely at the plot on the WA page).

Comment: Nobody is talking abount complex nonreal arguments $x$ here, only the function has limits when $x\to0$ with $x$ positive real and when $x\to0$ with $x$ negative real, and these two limits coincide.

Comment: ((Please do not erase your comments, especially when they are asking questions to which later comments answer.))

Comment: Pardon me, but I still don't understand why the limit for a function exists at a point [when you can approach the point from only one side](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/u6snnkabis).(the function is real valued)

Comment: Did you read my answer? Either one defines a real valued function on $x$ real, $x\gt0$ only, then the limit when $x\to0$ can only be (obviously) a limit *from the right*. Or, one defines a complex valued function on $x$ real, $x\gt0$ **and** $x\lt0$, then one obtains a function which happens to be real valued on $x\gt0$ and to be complex-valued on $x\lt0$ and which happens to have the *both-sided* limit $1$ at $0$, that is, when $x\to0$, $x\gt0$, **and** when $x\to0$, $x\lt0$.

Comment: Thanks.. your comment answered my question..

Comment: @Apurv this might provide some more clarity, but can we say that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists? If so then what is the right hand limit? If you're interested in some, this can be thought of as a topological problem (I'm guessing you're not familiar with the subject - I wouldn't say I am either) but topology does resolve this issue nicely!

Comment: @DanZimm More clarity through nonfamiliarity? Interesting.

Comment: @Did that was two different statements (or at least I meant it to be :P) i.e. clarity is provided in thinking about $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ and further knowledge can be found in looking into topology.

Answer (score 4):

We have using the Taylor series

$$e^{-x}+x-1\sim_0\frac{x^2}{2}$$
hence
$$\frac{x}{e^{-x}+x-1}\sim_0\frac2x$$
and then
$$\left(\frac{x}{e^{-x}+x-1}\right)^x=\exp\left(x\log \left(\frac{x}{e^{-x}+x-1}\right)\right)\sim_0\exp\left(x\log\left(\frac2x\right)\right)\xrightarrow{x\to0}e^0=1$$

Comment: No it's $0$ and of course this limit exists when $\log x$ exists i.e. for $x>0$.

Comment: then you can't call it a limit at $0$. What I am asking is that does the limit at $0$ exists? (The RHL may exist). Is it a matter of using language?